# Determine fn output type from input type

Tags: rust, types

I would like a function that returns f32 if the input is f32, for all other numeric inputs it should return f64.

A simplified example of the structure is this:

```
use num::{Num, NumCast, ToPrimitive, traits::Float};

fn example<N: Num + ToPrimitive, T: Float>(input: N) -> T {
    let output = input + N::one();
    NumCast::from(output).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", example::<f32, f32>(1f32));
    println!("{}", example::<u32, f64>(1u32));
}
```

is there a way to control the dispatch so that I can drop the turbofish and it will automatically map

f32 -> f32 and

anything else -> f64 ?

Comment: no, and it's not needed as show https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=133108cb1641b89478c735cb66b4f476 in rust you should trust

Comment: thanks, that's helpful but doesn't fully solve the problem. Is it possible to do it with one function instead of two separate functions?

Comment: again not needed the two function are just to show you rust infer system.

Comment: okay, but currently the dispatch is pushed to the user who has to know whether to call foo or bar. Is there a single interface function we can call that handles that instead?

Comment: yes, your `exemple()`.... you should really just test out your function instead of staying theoretical. practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a function which returns either `f32` or `f64` making decision in runtime. But you can implement such behavior using traits.

You can have two traits `ToF32` and `ToF64` and implement first one for `f32` only and `ToF64` for all other numeric types except `f32`. You will need a lot of boilerplate code to implement `ToF64` though. It can be compacted using macros.

```rust
use num::{NumCast, ToPrimitive, one, Integer};

trait ToF32 {
    fn example(self) -> f32;
}

impl ToF32 for f32 {
    fn example(self) -> f32 {
        let output = self + one::<Self>();
        NumCast::from(output).unwrap()
    }
}

trait ToF64 {
    fn example(self) -> f64;
}

impl<T: Integer + ToPrimitive> ToF64 for T {
    fn example(self) -> f64 {
        let output = self + one::<Self>();
        NumCast::from(output).unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", 1f32.example());
    println!("{}", 1u32.example());
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aca4f86231fea521b885818c36e40614)